# Amazon RedShift: Unique Column not being honored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I use the following query to create my table.

```
create table t1 (url varchar(250) unique);
```

Then I insert about 500 urls, twice. I am expecting that the second time I had the URLs that no new entries show up in my table, but instead my count value doubles for:

```
select count(*) from t1;
```

What I want is that when I try and add a url that is already in my table, it is skipped.
Have I declared something in my table deceleration incorrect?

I am using RedShift from AWS.

Sample

```
urlenrich=# insert into seed(url, source) select 'http://www.google.com', '1';
INSERT 0 1
urlenrich=# select * from seed;
          url          | wascrawled | source | date_crawled 
-----------------------+------------+--------+--------------
 http://www.google.com |          0 |      1 | 
(1 row)

urlenrich=# insert into seed(url, source) select 'http://www.google.com', '1';
INSERT 0 1
urlenrich=# select * from seed;
          url          | wascrawled | source | date_crawled 
-----------------------+------------+--------+--------------
 http://www.google.com |          0 |      1 | 
 http://www.google.com |          0 |      1 | 
(2 rows)
```

Output of \d seed

urlenrich=# \d seed

```
                  Table "public.seed"
    Column    |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 url          | character varying(250)      | 
 wascrawled   | integer                     | default 0
 source       | integer                     | not null
 date_crawled | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "seed_url_key" UNIQUE, btree (url)
```

Comment: I'm not surprised that I can't duplicate this behavior. What version of PostgreSQL? What does `select count(*) from t1;` return? What interface are you using? (pgAdminIII, psql, etc.) How many rows are NULL? (You can insert multiple NULL values in a column declared UNIQUE. Declaring it PRIMARY KEY might be a better idea.)

Comment: How about some sample data that demonstrates the uniqueness violation? Maybe even an http://sqlfiddle.com demo.

Comment: does it do the same thing if you `insert into seed(url,source) values('http://www.google.com',1);`  twice ?

Comment: What's the output of `\d seed`?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Tried PRIMARY KEY, still nothing

Comment: @muistooshort sqlfiddle wouldn't compile saying that duplicate entires

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Don't think so.... As I am just hitting up and issues the same insert command twice.

Comment: How many different schemas in your database?

Comment: Constraints in redshift are like traffic lights in china: merely a suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured out the problem

Amazon RedShift does not enforce constraints...

As explained here
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html

They said they may get around to changing it at some point.

NEW 11/21/2013
RDS has added support for PostGres, if you need unique and such an postgres rds instance is now the best way to go.

Comment: I don't think that they will add it soon as enforcing Unique Constraints / Primary Keys/ Foreign key will force them to hold an index including the key disturbed by the key (very similar to partitioned global index in Oracle) - Thus creating a huge overhead in the insert. we are just making sure the keys are ok in the source data / ETL process

Answer (score 4):

In redshift, constraints are recommended but doesn't take effect, constraints will just help to the query planner to select better ways to perform the query.

Usually, columnar databases do not manage indexes or constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Although Amazon Redshift doesn't support unique constraints, there are some ways to delete duplicated records that can be helpful.
See the following link for the details.

[copy data from Amazon s3 to Red Shift and avoid duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701385/copy-data-from-amazon-s3-to-red-shift-and-avoid-duplicate-rows/17587647)

Comment: RDS now supports postgres, so if you need a postgres database you no longer have to use RedShift.

Answer (score 1):

Primary and unique key enforcement in distributed systems, never mind column store systems, is difficult.  Both RedShift (Paracel) and Vertica face the same problems.

The challenge with a column store is that the question that is being asked is "does this table row have a relevant entry in another table row" but column stores are not designed for row operations.

In HP Vertica there is an explicit command to report on constraint violations.
In Redshift it appears that you have to roll your own.

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords, COUNT(DISTINCT {your PK_Column}) AS UniqueRecords
    FROM {Your table}
    HAVING COUNT(*)> COUNT(DISTINCT {your PK_Column})
```

Obviously, if you have a multi-column PK you have to do something more heavyweight.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT {PkColumns}
    FROM {Your Table}
    GROUP BY {PKColumns}
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1

) AS DT
```

If the above returns a value greater than zero then you have a primary key violation.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who:

- Needs to use redshift
- Wants unique inserts in a single query
- Doesn't care too much about query performance
- Only really cares about inserting a single unique value at a time

Here's an easy way to get it done

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMNS) 
    SELECT MY_UNIQUE_VALUE WHERE MY_UNIQUE_VALUE NOT IN (
        SELECT MY_UNIQUE_VALUE FROM MY_TABLE 
        WHERE MY_UNIQUE_COLUMN = MY_UNIQUE_VALUE
    )
```

Comment: Redshift is not meant to be used in this manor. Redshift should only be used for bulk loads, and duplicates are desired over dropping of any data.This should all be done as part of post processing. (Learned a lot since I asked the question)

Comment: As long as you're using COPY for your bulk loads, using this method to load data for low hit, low row schema's won't negatively impact your performance on Redshift. This isn't trying to make Redshift into Postgres, there are legitimate reasons to use this method.